# date greater than pl sql

Tags: plsql, where-clause

How do I compose a where clause I would like to query records where the pending application date is greater than the admit date in the following table:

[admitable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV8Yh.png)

Normally, the pending date is the earlier date.

Comment: where or how to get the pending application date ?

Comment: How is the the `>` operator not working as intended for you? Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a few moments to review [ask] and edit more details into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Can you say which databse is? Oracle? Postgres. If both application date and admit date are in the same format you can use > operator, eg:

```
    pending_application > admint_date
```

If want to exclude time and test only date, in oracle

```
trunc(pending_application) > trunc(admint_date)
```

Comment: Hi, yes, my apologies, this is Oracle 12c db.

Comment: The pending date has to be greater than all other possible decision dates. For example, a person could have admit_code 01 and admit_code 35, 99, 8A, 70, etc. all with their own dates.